# getting distinct member with multiple products

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a list of people who may have one product or up to 10 products.
I want to be able to categorize the individual by product categories.
For example:

```
Person| Product| Store_Online 
--------------------------------
A     | A_1    | Store
A     | A_2    | Online
B     | A_1    | Store
B     | A_1    | Store
C     | A_1    | Store
C     | A_1    | Online
C     | A_1    | Store
D     | A_1    | Online
```

I want to be able to show the following as a result:

```
Person| Product| Store_Online
--------------------------------
A     |2Products| Both
B     | Single  | Store
C     | Single  | Both
D     |Single   |Online
```

I can't think of something that would be able to give me what I'm hoping to get.

Doing a distinct will give me the single person, but I'm not positive what I may be able to use to get me the desirable result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simple conditional aggregation

**Example**

```
Select Person
      ,Product      = case when count(Distinct Product)      = 1 then 'Single' else concat(count(Distinct Product),'Products') end
      ,Store_Online = case when count(Distinct Store_Online) = 1 then max(Store_Online) else 'Both' end
  from @YourTable
 Group By Person
```

Returns

```
Person  Product     Store_Online
A       2Products   Both
B       Single      Store
C       Single      Both
D       Single      Online
```

Comment: Simple is better!! @John Thank you for your help!! This is exactly what i was hoping to get

Comment: @WWaldo Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.person, 
       (CASE WHEN Product_CNT > 1 THEN '2Products' ELSE 'Single' END),
       (CASE WHEN Store_Online_CNT > 1 THEN 'Both' ELSE Store_Online END)
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Product) AS Product_CNT, 
              COUNT(DISTINCT Store_Online) AS Store_Online_CNT
       FROM table t1
       WHERE t1.person = t.person
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Thank you @yogesh !!  I will try that and let you know  if that works

Comment: Thank you for the advice and help! I was able to use John's query to get the results I needed.